# Finding keys near other keys [C++]

Tags: c++

I'm sorry if the title is undescriptive, I'm not sure how to summarize my issue into a few words.

I'm looking to find which characters are physically near other characters on my QWERTY (UK, but I don't mind if you provide information specific to US) keyboard.

e.g:

```
charsNearChar('j') // OUTPUT -> U,I,H,K,N,M.
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around any solutions beside switch cases for each individual character, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you give each key an X and Y coordinate, and then calculate the difference between them using Pythagoras theorem, and those under a certain threshold are considered near?

Comment: That's a great idea @Matthew, I'll give it a try now!

Comment: @user15200288 -- What about keys that are physically longer / wider than others, such as the Enter key or Shift key?  Or are you assuming all keys are the same width and height?

Comment: You need to define 'near'. Prior to the above comment I would not have guessed that you meant Euclidean distance. Even though you said 'physically near' I took that to be a figure of speech.

Comment: My function would ideally only return letters or numbers so I don't think I'd need to take return or backspace into account, although if I needed to - I think I'd just assume that they are all the same width and height @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: I would just assign integer rows and columns to keys and then adjust my definition of "near" so that it does the right thing. So if Q is 1,1, W is 1, 2 and A is 2,1, and so, the definition of near just has to be: 1) Same row, +/- 1 on column, or 2) Lower row, same column or one greater, or 3) Higher row, same column or one less.

Comment: >`I can't seem to wrap my head around any solutions beside switch cases for each individual character` Think twice whether it would really be better to use a complicated, difficult to debug and difficult to extend solution that you *can't* wrap your head around. In fact, you can't even formally describe the requirement adequately.

Comment: "Adjacent Keys" is data. Do not use a switch case for data. Use a map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no (simple) calculation that you could perform to get the list of adjacent keys. You simply need to use an explicitly written list of adjacent keys for each key.

> any solutions beside switch cases

You don't need switch cases. What you're essentially asking for is a graph where nodes are keys and edges are to "adjacent" keys.

There are many ways to represent graphs. For your use case, perhaps an easy to understand, and reasonably fast choice is to use an associative map from key to its adjacency list (a vector of chars, or a string):

```
std::unordered_map<char, std::string> {
    {'J', "UIHKNM"},
    ....
};
```

---

Since you limit the functionality to alphanumeric keys, they have an interesting property of being in a hexagonal grid. Such grid could well be represented with a 2D matrix:

```
char grid[][] = {
    "123...",
     "QWE...",
      "ASD...",
       "ZXC...",
};
```

This representation has less repetition, and the adjacency lists can be generated form this matrix with an algorithm.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5ae7e938a7057a9